# Magento 2 Custom Widget set template data not render at frontend

Tags: php, magento, widget, magento2

I am working to create custom widget in custom extension. i follow [this](http://www.venustheme.com/how-to-create-magento-2-widget/) to create widget in my custom extension.All working fine but data not showing in the template `$this->setTemplate('widget/viewed_list.phtml');`
Below my code:

> Technologymindz/Instagramfeed/Block/Widget/Instawidget.php

```
<?php
namespace Technologymindz\Instagramfeed\Block\Widget;

class Instawidget extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template implements \Magento\Widget\Block\BlockInterface
{

    public function _toHtml()
    {
        $this->setTemplate('widget/viewed_list.phtml');

    }


}
```

> Technologymindz/Instagramfeed/etc/widget.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<widgets xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../Magento/Widget/etc/widget.xsd">
    <widget id="tm_customwidget" class="Technologymindz\Instagramfeed\Block\Widget\Instawidget">
        <label translate="true">Instagram Feeds</label>
        <description>Show Your Instagram Feeds Anywhere</description>
        <parameters>
                        <parameter name="tmfeedtoshow" xsi:type="select" required="true" visible="true">
                            <label>Show Latest Feeds</label>
                            <options>
                                <option name="default" value="12" selected="true">
                                    <label translate="true">12</label>
                                </option>
                                <option name="list" value="24">
                                    <label translate="true">24</label>
                                </option>                              
                            </options>
                        </parameter>
            <parameter name="tmview_type" xsi:type="select" required="true" visible="true">
                            <label>Select View Type</label>
                            <options>
                                <option name="default" value="widget/viewed_grid.phtml" selected="true">
                                    <label translate="true">Grid View</label>
                                </option>
                                <option name="list" value="widget/viewed_list.phtml">
                                    <label translate="true">List View</label>
                                </option>                              
                            </options>
                        </parameter>
        </parameters>                
    </widget>
</widgets>
```

> Technologymindz/Instagramfeed/view/frontend/widget/viewed_list.phtml

```
<?php
echo $this->getTmview_type();
echo 'Welcome';
?>
```

Data output not showing for `viewed_list.phtml` but if i set something in Block `_toHtml()`function than it shows.

```
public function _toHtml()
    {
        return '<p class="hello">Hello world!</p>';
    }
```

i want manage output in `.phtml` not in Block, hope i can get fix for this or any better tutorial for Magento 2 custom Widget data render at template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok,after lot of research, i found a gentle article [here](http://cookie-code.net/magento-2/how-to-create-magento-2-widget/) and this fix issue for me. i did completely removed `_toHtml` function

Solution worked for me:

```
protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setTemplate('widget/viewed_list.phtml');
    }
```